# how can detect in android which protocol the call uses:?

Tags: android, telephony

I want to make android apps but we need some information related to protocol at the calling time or receiving time of phone .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class to retroeve current network information.